# How are floating IP's and system subnet provided for External Network effecting actual hypervisor

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, hypervisor

Intalled openstack 17.0.3 in my centOS VM using packstack installation method. I want to know How are floating IP's and system subnet provided for External Network effecting actual hypervisor.